# (Psychology research) Is it appropriate or coherent to standardize these variables?

Tags: standardization, psychometrics

I am doing a project where I'm analyzing various lexical dimensions of speech from folktales from 10 countries. And the program, LIWC, returns a value for each category with that value representing what percentage of the words fell into that category. So a value of 5 for Hostility_America means that 5% of the words in American folk tales had to do with hostility.

If I want to compare how, say, the dimensions of hostility and affect are related across my 10 countries, would I standardize each variable dimension? That is: Should I be looking at how the standardized values of hostility and affect vary?